Proof assistants for undergraduate analysis
I am looking for a program that would help me prove some elementary inequalities. What I mean by that is that:

I would tell the program some term written with usual functions, then I would tell him « use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality like this », « distribute this linear function over this sum », « apply Fubini’s theorem to switch these two integrals », etc.;
It would show me step by step what the « current term » looks like;
When the proof is finished, it would output a text that is a program itself, such that anyone wanting to check my proof would only have to compile the program.

Now, I think that any proof assistant would allow me to do that, but is there a user-friendly one, that can be used by people that have never used any proof assistant before?
I am sure that some people working in analytic number theory (which is, as far as I know, a field where proofs are usually full of « elementary » but very, very long and subtle inequality proofs) should already be using this kind of stuff (I mean, I hope they are, this would make refereeing much easier).
EDIT: after reading Andrej Bauer’s answer, I realized that my question wasn’t precise enough.
To set an arbitrary threshold, let me give you an example: when I write proofs in $\LaTeX$ of this kind of things, I spend some time copying the current term, paste it below, make some identical changes on different terms, writing « because of Lemma 3.1 » in the margin, get worried about overfull hboxes, make some mistakes that I spot only after trying to prove three other lemmas based on this one, so I have to change everything, etc.; all this for a proof that only a few people will have the courage to check by hand.
I am willing to invest a lot of time in learning how to use proof assistant that, after some effort to get proficient with it, would allow me to write automatically checkable proofs in roughly the same time as the time it takes me to typeset them into $\LaTeX$. If there is one, can you tell me which one it I would be?
I have always been afraid of learning Coq or Lean (the only ones I have heard of) because I have the (uninformed opinion) that since they have been designed for a general purpose, they might not be very nice to use for such a specific (and, to my opinion, much more elementary) purpose.

Prepare to be disappointed, proof assistants are nowhere near able to do this sort of thing. Especially for something like analytic number theory

(I have amended the answer after the OP changed the question. I leave below the original answer for posterity.)
Your expectation that something is to be gained by having a special-purpose proof assistant is a bit misguided. It's like expecting that having a special-purpose LaTeX for analysis would bring advantages over general LaTeX. Both LaTeX and proof assistants are very flexible and can be adapted to all sorts of tasks because they are highly programmable. If there is enough interest, someone will create special-purpose tactics for dealing with inequalities (and in fact people already have, ask another question).
I would recommend that you learn Lean at this point, because it's taking over the world of formalized math quite rapidly. There are many tutorials that you can learn from. To my students I recommend the Natural numbers game, and any other one that interests them, and after that Mathematics in Lean.
Original answer:
There is no proof assistant like that at present, at least not one that you will be able to use without investing some time into learning how to use it. The initial investment is similar to that of learning LaTeX, I would say.

I would gladly learn how to use a proof assistant. You made a good point that I will add in my question. I would be happy if (after some personal training to become efficient) the process of proving would be less or equally time-consuming than the process of writing the proof in $\LaTeX$ (where we usually can run into tiring layout issues when writing long chain of - trivial - inequalities).

I am sorry, I edited my question because I realized it wasn’t precise enough.

Experts perhaps in some cases reach the level where formalization is equally time-consuming as LaTeX typesetting. I general, I think the formalization process is still slower than on-paper proofs. The correct question to ask is: how much time are you willing to trade for knowing that your proofs are 100% correct?

Even if it would be twice the time, it would still be okay, I guess. The main goal is to prevent me from my own computational mistakes!

Twice the time is definitely achievable, I would say. Anyhow, I updated my answer.

As a Mizar author I recommend Mizar of course. In my opinion the advantage of Mizar in comparison to other proof checkers is the readability and write-ability since Mizar only uses ASCII symbols that are directly on your keyboard.
Here is how Fubini's theorem is formalized in Mizar:
::$N Fubini`s theorem
theorem :: MESFUN13:30
for X1,X2 being non empty set, S1 being SigmaField of X1,
S2 being SigmaField of X2, M1 being sigma_Measure of S1,
M2 being sigma_Measure of S2, f being PartFunc of [:X1,X2:],ExtREAL,
SX1 being Element of S1
st M1 is sigma_finite & M2 is sigma_finite
 & f is_integrable_on Prod_Measure(M1,M2) & X1 = SX1
holds
  ex U be Element of S1 st M1.U = 0
    & (for x being Element of X1 st x in U` holds
          ProjPMap1(f,x) is_integrable_on M2)
    & Integral2(M2,|.f.|)|U` is PartFunc of X1,REAL
    & Integral2(M2,f) is (SX1\U)-measurable
    & Integral2(M2,f)|U` is_integrable_on M1
    & Integral2(M2,f)|U` in L1_Functions M1
    & (ex g be Function of X1,ExtREAL st
         g is_integrable_on M1 & g|U` = Integral2(M2,f)|U`
       & Integral(Prod_Measure(M1,M2),f) = Integral(M1,g));

As for the speed, I would say once you are versed in the language and library and know how the proof works, you spend like 1.5 the time'* it takes to write the proof in LaTeX to write it in Mizar, with the added benefit that there are ways to convert your Mizar proof into LaTeX.
'* this is my estimate, maybe based on how fast I am with Mizar or how slow I am with LaTeX
Mizar bibliography can be found here, including my introduction to the MML. I'm also currently writing A Practical Guide To Mizar, but it is a work in progress.

As Andrej says, nothing is quite as you want, but we are getting very close, when we combine tools like formal theorem provers (like Lean), AI chat (like ChatGPT), code assistants (like CoPilot), and ITP-specific AI (like Lean CoPilot or LLMLean).
For example, say I ask ChatGPT the following:

Convert the following reasoning into Lean 4 using calc mode.
The goal is to prove $(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i y_i)^2 \leq
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty x_i^2 y_j^2$ where $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ are in $\ell_2$:
$(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i y_i)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^2) (\sum_{j=0}^\infty y_j^2)$ by Cauchy Swartz
$= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^2 y_j^2 $ moving the sum inside by linearity of sums
$= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty x_i^2 y_j^2 $ swaping sums by Fubini's theorem for sums.

It responds with the following Lean code:
import Mathlib.Analysis.SpecialFunctions.Pow -- Import necessary modules

open Classical -- For classical logic, if needed

example (x y : ℕ → ℝ) (hx : summable (λ i, x i ^ 2)) (hy : summable (λ i, y i ^ 2)) :
  (∑' i, x i * y i) ^ 2 ≤ ∑' i, ∑' j, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2 := by
calc
  (∑' i, x i * y i) ^ 2
      ≤ (∑' i, x i ^ 2) * (∑' j, y j ^ 2) : by apply real_inner_smul_sq; exact ⟨hx, hy⟩ -- Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
  _   = ∑' j, ∑' i, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2 : tsum_mul_tsum_eq_tsum_double hx hy -- Move sums inside by linearity
  _   = ∑' i, ∑' j, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2 : tsum_fubini' (λ i j, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2) hx hy -- Swap sums by Fubini's theorem

Unfortunately, it is not completely correct.  One problem is that ChatGPT mixes up Lean 3 and Lean 4 syntax.  Also, ChatGPT doesn't have access to the Lean environment or the Mathlib documentation, so the proofs are often filled with made-up theorem names.
If I manually clean up the syntax (using a bit of basic Lean 4 experience, not too much), we get:
import Mathlib -- Import necessary modules

example (x y : ℕ → ℝ) (hx : Summable (λ i ↦ x i ^ 2)) (hy : Summable (λ i ↦ y i ^ 2)) :
  (∑' i, x i * y i) ^ 2 ≤ ∑' i, ∑' j, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2 := by
calc
  (∑' i, x i * y i) ^ 2
      ≤ (∑' i, x i ^ 2) * (∑' j, y j ^ 2) := by sorry -- Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
  _   = ∑' j, ∑' i, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2 := by sorry -- Move sums inside by linearity
  _   = ∑' i, ∑' j, x i ^ 2 * y j ^ 2 := by sorry -- Swap sums by Fubini's theorem

I omitted the proofs of each step, because again they didn't seem correct.  And even with my simple searching I couldn't find the needed lemmas.  (I didn't try more advanced AI like Lean Copilot or LLMLean.)
But you can already get a feeling for how existing theorem provers like Lean, along with a combination of AI tools could really start to fit the vision you laid out.
Until that time, I think learning Lean/Mathlib (or Isabelle/AFP, or Coq/MathComp) would start to bring you a lot of the way there.  And existing AI tools like ChatGPT or Copilot already help with this translation!

Also, as you point out, many of the techniques in analysis are well-established, common, and elementary, so even if Lean’s Mathlib currently doesn’t have the needed lemmas or if AI tools can’t easily find them, that will soon change as more and more of these arguments are formalized in Lean (manually or automatically).  Indeed, I think analysis is an area very ripe for building up AI auto-formalization specifically because of these properties of analysis proofs.

Wow, didn't know that Lean is used by ChatGPT already!

@SK19 Well, not too well from the example above. :). But many language with enough data on the open internet it would give a reasonable attempt at.  It is probably better at Coq and Isabelle since they are older.
